# PHP get if string is a time in the format 00:00

Tags: php, regex

I have a string which may be a time or may be something else entirely.  I want to find out if the string is in the format 00:00.  I don't need to check whether the string is a valid time (ie not something like 25:98), just whether the string is in that format.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The regex would be `/^\d{2}:\d{2}$/`. Which matches a string if and only if it contains 2 digits before the colon and two digits after the colon.

Here is a PHP if/else condition with the above regex:

```
if (preg_match('/^\d{2}:\d{2}$/', $time)) {
    // it is in the time format
} else {
    // it is not in the time format
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to add a check for 12 hrs 60 mins and 60 seconds too? as if i write 56:47 that is not a time.

Answer (score 2):

And regex for that would be `^[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}$`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
/\b\d{2}:\d{2}\b/
```

`\b` is a word boundary to ensure that there is nothing else before or ahead

`\d` is a digit, `\d{2}` means two digits.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (preg_match('/^[0-9]{2,2}:[0-9]{2,2}$/', $string))
{
    // ...
}
```